# Google Geocode before Form Submit

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps

This might seem a stupid question but it has been keeping me busy for a whole day.

What I whould like to achieve is by using Google Geocoder geocode an address before submitting my search form.

I have the following code:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>


$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    var a = $('#address').val();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({"address" : a }, function(result, status){
        // Extract latitude and longitude
        $('#lat').val(latitude);
    });
});
```

Everything works as it should except that the form is submitted before `lat` and `lng` are set!

Could anyone please shed a light into my problem please?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

I have also tried using `onclick` on the submit button, `onsubmit` in the form and jQuery `.validator()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you want to stop the form submit from happening; this could otherwise happen potentially faster than the asynchronous geocode request would complete.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Then you want to move the form submission into the geocoding response handler.

```
geocoder.geocode({"address" : a }, function(result, status){
    ...
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

The problem you'd then have I think is the recursive call to the form submit.  So instead I'd say have  your event handler not on the form submit, but on the submit button click (there's probably a neater way of doing this).  Preventing the submit button's default action, but still allowing us to then submit the form.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitButton" />

$('#submitButton').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var a = $('#address').val();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({"address" : a }, function(result, status){
        // Extract latitude and longitude
        $('#lat').val(latitude);
        $('#myForm').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm and thanks for the clear explanation :)